# How do you create an arrow for sub navigation like this?

Tags: html, css

How do you create the arrow that appears when you hover over "Reviews" on this site?

http://mac.appstorm.net/category/reviews/

I want to create this via css but am not sure how to do so.  Also what is the correct "term" for that?

Thanks!

Comment: Correct term for a CSS arrow? Why "CSS arrow" of course! ;)

Comment: Ha sounds good to me! When I search for "css arrow" I literally get the arrow icon, and I just want the arrow poking out of the box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see an example at [Simple Stock Search](http://simplestocksearch.com) if you register and hover over one of the menu options.

The CSS for such an arrow is:

```
.reviews:after
{
    content: "";
    z-index: 9999;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -10px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -10px;
    border-top: 10px solid red;
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
}
```

Visit this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9y2Ff/) for a demo.

Answer (score 2):

from [cssarrowplease.com](http://cssarrowplease.com/)

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/W2Dcb/1/)**

HTML

```
<span class="arrow_box">test</span>
```

CSS

```
.arrow_box:hover {
    position: relative;
    background: #88b7d5;
    border: 4px solid #c2e1f5;
    width: 100px;
    display:inline-block;
    height: 25px;
}
.arrow_box:hover:after, .arrow_box:hover:before {
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    border: solid transparent;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.arrow_box:hover:after {
    border-color: rgba(136, 183, 213, 0);
    border-top-color: #88b7d5;
    border-width: 5px;
    margin-left: -5px;
}
.arrow_box:hover:before {
    border-color: rgba(194, 225, 245, 0);
    border-top-color: #c2e1f5;
    border-width: 11px;
    margin-left: -11px;
}
```